# Indexes in axapta

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365, dynamics-ax7

Hiii, 
I am new to axapta

I have a table in which I want two fields together should act as a primary key. Is this possible or not

If not is there any alternate way to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Yes, this is possible. If you don't know how to do it, I recommend you get some training in D365FO development first. [80730AE: Development Basics in Microsoft Dynamics AX](https://mbspartner.microsoft.com/AX/CourseModules/1181) is a good place to start.

Comment: I can't login in that link

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples in the AOT.

For example, table `MarkupTrans` has primary index `TableRecIdIdx` created from 3 fields (`TransRecId`, `TransTableId` and `LineNum`); table `VendInvoiceInfoLine` has primary index `TableRefIdx` created from 5 fields (`TableRefId`, `ParmId`, `OrigPurchId`, `LineNum` and `RecId`), etc.

Comment: Thanks I'll also refer some more example

Comment: I got my answer we have to create a index with 2 or more fields and set the allow duplicates to NO and alternate key to yes in the index then go to table properties and set the replacement key as your index.

Comment: Your question was about a primary key, not an alternate key. There is a maximum of one primary key per table, whereas a table can have several alternate keys. Replacement key is a different thing, it just defines what fields would appear on forms to helpfully identify each record. So your comment doesn't really answer your own question. More on the topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh812105.aspx